# What are the most idiomatic ways to combine tensors in torch?

Tags: lua, torch

I'm confronted with concatenating three tensors together so that 3 px1 tensors become one 3px1 tensor.

The most succinct I could come up with was:

```
torch.Tensor{v2:totable(),v4:totable(),v6:totable()}:view(3*p,1)
```

Are there ways to do this without converting to tables and back to tensors? It seems like there should be a generic way of concatenating tensors along some specified dimension assuming they have compatible shapes.

I can see how it would be possible to write such a function, does one not exist?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
a = torch.randn(3,1)
b = torch.randn(3,1)
c = torch.randn(3,1)

d = torch.cat(a,b,1):cat(c,1)

print(d)
```

Comment: What an obvious name for this function! I didn't notice it because it's not discussed on the [tensor doc](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md). Is there more comprehensive api docs that list all the functions? I realize I can list them in the `th` console using tab completion and then query the help for each method. Are these not all online somewhere in somewhere in HTML?

Comment: @KevinBullaughey The docs for `tensor.cat` are in [Mathematical Operations](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/maths.md#res-torchcat-res-x_1-x_2-dimension-d) in GitHub repo.

Comment: Ah! Somehow I missed that file. Thanks @rpattiso for pointing it out.